# Sequelize - return single column from associated table as custom column

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have two models: User and Images. User has `profile_image_id` column.

When i get the user with `include {model:Images, as:'profileImage', attributes:['filename']}` I get `profileImage` as object with `filename` as property.

Is there a way in Sequelize to get that 'filename' as a property of User model?
Meaning to execute

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, i.filename 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN images i ON i.id = u.profile_image_id 
WHERE u.id = 1
```

What works for now is defining `VIRTUAL` attribute `profileImageFIlename` on user and then populating it in `afterFind` function of User model. But it seems like a lot of extra work and unnecessary data.

Is there a better way except raw query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that there isn't a way to do it that would be "less work". Even in your example SQL query you reference `i.filename` using the alias that you created for the related `images` table. This effectively maps to `User.images.filename`, which is just as usable as `User.profile_image_file`.

If you would like `profile_image_id` to exist as a `VIRTUAL` field on `User` then you are doing it the correct way - `VIRTUAL` fields won't be persisted to the database schema, so you would need to set them from some other source. In this case, the related `images` table provides the value and you will need to set it in the `afterfind()` hook.

If you don't care about it being on the `User` `Instance` or `Model` and just want to access the value in the results without having to traverse the object, you can use something like the following to alias the column by leveraging [`Sequelize.literal()`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#literalval-sequelizeliteral).

```js
User.findById(1, {
  attributes: {
    include: [[Sequelize.literal('images.filename'), 'profile_image_file']],
  },
  include: [{ model: Images, as: 'images', attributes: [] }]
})
.then((user) => {
    // There will be a user.dataValues.profile_image_file value populated
    // but not a user.profile_image_file unless you set it in afterFind()
    console.log(user.dataValues);
});
```

This will result in SQL of

```sql
SELECT `user`.`id`, `user`.`name`, images.filename AS `profile_image_file`
FROM `user` AS `user` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `images` AS `images` ON `user`.`profile_image_id` = `images`.`id` 
WHERE `user`.`id` = 1;
```